# sql server: one file for all the application or is it better to make it multiple db files?

Tags: sql-server, database

is it better to put different parts of the app in seperate databases or in a single database file. for example putting forum tables in one database file and putting the blogs tables in another db ??

Answer (score 4):

Separate databases probably don't make sense but, assuming SQL Server 2005 or later, I would encourage you to look into using schemas to logically separate these functional areas. See Buck Woody's article [SQL Server Best Practices: User-Defined Schemas](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckwoody/archive/2009/06/18/sql-server-best-practices-user-defined-schemas.aspx) as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

> is it better to put different parts of the app in seperate databases or in a single database file

Ah - waht exactly do you ask here? Is this about DATABASES or about DATABASE FILES - a database can have many filegroups which each can have many files.

Depends on size and IO requirements. I have seen databases with 28 groups of multiple files each, to optimize the IO bandwidth of the underlying SAN which was limiting every LUN (and that had multiple files per LUN) to 256 outstanding requests.

if you get into higher end requirements, that makes sense. Likely for you it does not, as your working indicates you dont really know databases, and so you wont work on a multi terabyte high end system ;)

Comment: i'm using sql express so there is no such a thing as file groups.

Comment: Well, then you also can never run daatabase sizes where it matters. 10gb max limit - in my world, 1000gb is small.